# "Operation not permitted" on using os.setuid( ) [python]

Tags: python, operating-system, privileges, setuid

I'm trying to build a platform to launch some scripts. This scripts are placed in home folder of each user. Every launch should be done with each user id so, I'm doing, for each user, this:

```
user_id = pwd.getpwnam( user )[ 3 ]
user_home = pwd.getpwnam( user )[ 5 ]

os.chdir( user_home )
os.setuid( user_id )

subprocess.Popen( shlex.split( "user_script.py" ) )
```

But, when python trys to do `os.setuid( user_id )` it raise this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launcher.py", line XX, in <module>

OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

By the way, the user who starts this script is in the root group (on GNU/linux OS) and it has all the root privileges.

If I try to launch the same code with root user I get a different error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

If someone can help me to understand what's happening please...

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692720/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only root can do a setuid, being in the root-group is not enough.

Comment: It's truth that only root user can do a `os.setuid`, but in the case I've tried using the `root` user of the system. I should add this code is in a "daemon-process" and, I think, that's the problem. I've solved it doing a `os.fork` and doing the `os.setuid` and the `subprocess.Popen` in the child.

Answer (score 2):

Only superuser can change uid whenever it feels like it, just adding the user to the root group is not enough.

`setuid(2)` for example mentions:

```
 The setuid() system call is permitted if the specified ID is equal to the
 real user ID or the effective user ID of the process, or if the effective
 user ID is that of the super user.
```

On Linux, there's also:

```
   Under Linux, setuid() is implemented like the POSIX version with the 
   _POSIX_SAVED_IDS feature.  This allows a set-user-ID (other than  root)
   program to drop all of its user privileges, do some un-privileged work, and
   then reengage the original effective user ID in a secure manner.
```

I don't even know if Python directly implements this, but it's not exactly what you want anyway.

So the short answer is: Start the initial process as root.

If you're worried about security, start two processes, one as root, one as non-privileged user, and have the non-privileged process communicate with the root process with a socket. This is a more advanced setup though...

Comment: It's not necessary to start the process as root (or uid 0), any sufficiently privileged user will do. However, allowing a user to `setuid` allows her to become root, so it's effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted` indicates the user who starts the script has insufficient privileges. Being in the root group is not enough, it actually needs the **`CAP_SETUID`** capability.

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` is probably an unrelated error. You should have a look at its stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
subprocess.Popen( shlex.split( "user_script.py" ) )
```

confuses me in manifold ways.

1. The `shlex.split()` seems to be redundant, as there is nothing to split.
2. Better put `Popen()`'s parameter in a list.
3. If `user_script.py` has no execute permissions, even root cannot do that.

Comment: It's true that `shlex.split` is redundant. It was an example of the situation: In the real case I can't know if the "process to call" will have or not arguments so, in my opinion, `shlex.split` is necessary. Thanks for your answer and your patience.

Answer (score -1):

you also use setuid permission . That is give ,

```
       chmod 4755 script.py
```

Now even from normal user if you execute the program it will switch as that particular use. You won't get any permission issues .

Comment: This is not supported in all operating systems as the use of an interpreter introduces a security vulnerability. See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html for a more complete explanation.